# How create a flashable zip programmatically?

Tags: java, android, zip

I have a compress class

```
public class Compress {
  private static final int BUFFER = 80000;

  private String[] _files;
  private String _zipFile;

  public Compress(String[] files, String zipFile) {
    _files = files;
    _zipFile = zipFile;

  }

  public void zip() {
    try  {
      BufferedInputStream origin = null;
      FileOutputStream dest = new FileOutputStream(_zipFile);

      ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(dest));

      byte data[] = new byte[BUFFER];

      for(int i=0; i < _files.length; i++) {
       Log.d("add:",_files[i]);
        Log.v("Compress", "Adding: " + _files[i]);
        FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(_files[i]);
        origin = new BufferedInputStream(fi, BUFFER);
        ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(_files[i].substring(_files[i].lastIndexOf("/") + 1));
        out.putNextEntry(entry);
        int count;
        while ((count = origin.read(data, 0, BUFFER)) != -1) {
          out.write(data, 0, count);
        }
        origin.close();
      }

      out.close();
    } catch(Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }

}
```

Is possible use this class to create flashable zip?

Comment: Well, if you _flash your zip_ in public, that can get you in trouble. Or did I misunderstand something regarding what a **flashable ZIP** is? Would you mind explaining what _extra requirements_ such a compressed file would have to fulfill - even by pointing to an ofsite resource?

Comment: define "flashable" (please just define and avoid any picture of your actual zip)

Comment: I mean, i what create a simple file explorer. When i take an apk for example, i what compress it and make it flashable from recovery. I don't know if it's possible.

Comment: @David_D are you using "flashable" in place of side loading? Side loading is when you install an app through adb or through the recovery system.

Comment: The goal i want to reach is this: have the possibility to take 1,2,3,n apk files saved in my sdcard and create a only one zip file. This zip it will be flashable so when someone change rom or something else can instal this zip from recovery with all his apps. Something like this. Understand? Like the google apps